# how to check validity of /etc/logrotate.d/syslog

Tags: linux, logs, syslog, logrotate

we want to check the validity of the configuration file  `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog`

and that because we made some changes on that file from our bash script

so we use the following approach to check the file  `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog`

```
logrotate  /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
```

I will give example

```
more  /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
/var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
{
    size 1024M
    rotate 5
    compress
    dateext
    missingok
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

the above file will set log rotate to the logs as cron , maillog , messages , etc

so just to check the case when file is wrong then we add wrong syntax as

```
more  /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
/var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
{
    size 1024M
    rotate 5
    compress
    dateext
    missingok
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}

bug here syntax <----
```

so I will re-run the cli as

```
 logrotate  /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
error: /etc/logrotate.d/syslog:13 unknown option 'bug' -- ignoring line
 echo $?
0
```

but as we can see the std output is still 0 ,

so I just want to know what is the preferred approach to check the file - `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog` , ( when we are used this cli in bash script )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logrotate` has a `-d` option, which will list all the actions it would take based on the given configuration file, and flag any errors, *without* actually taking any action (so no file will be rotated).

Errors in the configuration file, whether they cause parsing issues (*e.g.* unbalanced braces) or not (as in your example), don’t result in a non-zero exit code. You need to look for `error:` in the output from `logrotate` – note that this goes to standard error, not standard output:

```
logrotate -d /path/to/configuration |& grep -qv error:
```

(assuming bash).

Non-zero exit codes are returned when `logrotate` encounters a runtime problem, *e.g.* if it can’t read one of the files it needs to rotate.